# using as for alias in javascript

Tags: typescript

```
export const ACTIONS = {
  delete: 'delete' as 'delete'
}
```

I don't understand this piece of code. I get it when I can use `ACTIONS.delete` but what's the 'as' doing here?

Answer (score 3):

It's needed because, if you don't, the object will be automatically widened to `delete: string`:

[image]

which may well not be precise enough typing for wherever it's used elsewhere. The intent of this code is for referencing `ACTIONS.delete` to give the type `'delete'`, and not the (much wider) type `string`.

An arguably better way of doing this is to use `as const` on the whole object, which reduces the possibility of typos and can apply to all properties, instead of having to do so for each individual property.

```
export const ACTIONS = {
  delete: 'delete'
} as const;
```

Comment: for autocomplete I don't 'feel' the difference